# The HITS Algorithm and its Authority Graph

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, algorithms

I'm currently reading over [this](https://www.math.hmc.edu/~ward/paperpdfs/hitsheaderbw6Jan05.pdf) article about the HITS searching algorithm (note that this question doesn't require knowledge of HITS, only that of basic matrix theory).

On page 14, Definition 4.3, a **directed** graph G is transformed into a graph G' by:

1. Defining the vertex set of $G'$ by those vertices in $G$ with positive in degree,
2. Defining the **undirected** edge set $E(G')$ as $\{\{i,j\}\in G' : \exists \hspace{0.05in} k \in G \text{ s.t. } (k,i) \text{ and } (k,j) \in E(G)\}$,
3. Adding a loop to all $i \in G'$ for each $k$ pointing to $i$ in $G$.

As an example, take the following Adjacency Matrix associated with a graph $G$ (a link to the graph can be found in the comments):

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then $E(G') = \{ \{1,4 \}, \{1,4\} \}$ and $G'$ is: [Undirected Graph of G'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqS4M.png).

The claim in the paper is that $A^TA$ is the adjacency matrix for $G'$, where

$$
A^TA = \begin{bmatrix}
3&0&0&2\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
2&0&0&2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

All of the entries match up with the graph $G'$, apart from $(A^TA)_{11}$ and $(A^TA)_{33}$, which I believe should be 2 and 0 respectively.

My thoughts are that I've made a mistake in the construction of the graph, as the matrix was calculated through MATLAB so will be correct.

If anyone can see where I've gone wrong or perhaps misinterpreted the paper, that would be great.

Comment: The link for the graph $G$ is: http://tinypic.com/r/17bcph/9

Comment: I think the issue may be through an ambiguous definition of terms in the paper. Whilst $k$ is defined in Definition 4.3, it doesn't appear to follow through in the discussion that follows, and is just **any** node from the graph $G$. This means that the number of loops for each vertex in $G'$ are simply the indegree of the vertex in $G$. If anyone could verify this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. The authors make use of the same symbol $k$, but in a different context.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that although $k$ is used in the definition preceding the discussion, the properties of $k$ do not follow through. The loops on each node in $G'$ simply represent the presence of an incoming link, and hence summing the loops for each node represents its indegree.